# Resource for pulling NBA On/Off Stats for a single game?

Tags: statistics, nba

I was wondering if there was a resource that allowed me to see On/Off statistics for a single player, in a unique game.

For example -- Can I see the effect of On/Off of LeBron James (FG%, 3PT%...) had on his Christmas game in 2017?

When I go to stats.nba.com, I only see the aggregate for the whole year. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to Sports Stack Exchange! Here's a website where you can find WOWY (with or without you) stats for NBA, specified to your query:

Team with Lebron in that game: http://nbawowy.com/ho3q1tufq2v#/ui09dmp08a
36.1 FG%, 43.8 3PT%

Team without Lebron in that game: http://nbawowy.com/ho3q1tufq2v#/mtt6soymogm
12.5% FG%, 25% 3PT%

You can click "swap" on the left to change players from On/Off, view their effect on the whole team or specific teammates, change the date range, and even play with teammate combos.

Hope this helps!